# Is it possible to specifiy which step implementation to use in behave?

Tags: python, automation, python-behave

My test suite have features/scenarios for both desktop and mobile. 
some steps will eventually have the same name (i.e., when I go to home page, when i click order ... etc)

the implementation though would be different between mobile and desktop and the only solution I can come up with right now is to slightly change the scenario name `when I go to home page on phone` but I'm still looking for a way to specify which implementation to use.

I would also go for a better setup if you can recommend something (for example building two test suites, one for mobile and one for desktop) but it seems that that will create more work than it saves.

Answer (score 1):

In my current Behave-based UI test framework, we rely on

> Write once, test everywhere

principle. Meaning, the Gherkin is declarative, specifying via annotations/tags which scenario is applicable for desktop web or mobile. The names, steps and flow is the same for both platforms. The actual handling is done via [DSL layer](https://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html) and [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/python/example) to pick up proper driver and flow at runtime. So, from design point of view it looks like this:

```
                              ===========================
                              | Gherkin (feature files) |
                              ===========================
                                          |
                         =====================================
                         | Step definitions (step_functions) |
                         =====================================
                                          |
                            ===============================
                            |            DSL              |
                            | (domain_models, strategies) |
                            |     e.g. login, register    |
                            ===============================
                                          |
                      ==============================================
                      |              Selenium Wrappers             |
                      |    (facade, decorators, adapters, proxy)   |
                      |e.g. atoms/element_actions.py or elementium |
                      ==============================================
                                          |
                         =========================================
                        |          Automation code              |
                        | (python bindings, protractor porting) |
                        =========================================
                                   /                  \
          _________________________________________________________________
                                SELENIUM ARCHITECTURE HERE
                              /                            \
                     ==============                 =================
                     | appium_api |                 | webdriver_api |
                     ==============                 =================
                            |                               |
                    =======   ===========    ==============   ===============
                    | iOS |   | Android |    |ChromeDriver|   |FirefoxDriver|
                    =======   ===========    ==============   ===============
```

All you need to do is pass custom flags to your specific/CI run, like so `-D platform=desktop -D browser=chrome`. This can be picked up via TagsManager and executed to proper strategy via dispatch mapping.

So, you don't need

> building two test suites, one for mobile and one for desktop